# Using the NCDC's Climate Data Online API with Java

Tags: java, rest, web-services, noaa

I have never used a RESTful API. I want to use [this](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2) API to get historical weather data, but I can't find a simple tutorial taking me from end to end making an app that uses a RESTful API in Java. I'm not sure what steps I should take to get the data.

The steps listed on the [getting started page](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted) are not Java specific, so I'm not sure how to use that info. I have requested a token and got it, so I'm good on that front.

What I need help with is getting **a minimal example showing how, with just a token and formatted URL, you can get JSON data from the API**.

Some things I've looked into are [javax.ws.rs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) and [jersey client](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/), but I'm not sure how to use those either.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a framework you want to use? I would suggest springboot

Comment: I will look into Spring Boot. I never knew frameworks existed (yeah I'm new to this side of Java).

Comment: I you have any questions after looking into that, edit the question (or make a new one) and shoot me a message, I might be able to help you

Comment: Thanks. I just applied for the IntelliJ student pack to get Spring integration. Hopefully this goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fetch you can do:

```
fetch(url, {options}) 
.then(data => { 
    // Do some stuff here 
}) 
.catch(err => { 
    // Catch and display errors 
})
```

Where the url is the one from the getting started page.
And you can get whatever data you need from data.
Say you need to save just the name in a local var, then you do:

```
.then(data => { 
    name = data.name
})
```